# Generalized Thomas Ordowski conjecture at OEIS sequence A002326

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, divisors-multiples, oeis

OEIS is the online encyclopedia of integer sequences, Here is the link to the sequence $A002326$: https://oeis.org/A002326

For $n\geq 0$, the $n$th term in the sequence is defined as: $a(n)$ equals the smallest natural number $m$ such that $(2n+1)\mid (2^m-1)$.

There is a conjecture that was posed by Thomas Ordowski at the page of the mentioned sequence, and I posed a generalization of his conjecture.
The non-generalized conjecture states that if $p$ is an odd prime; then $a((p^3-1)/2)=p\cdot a((p^2-1)/2)$.

The generalized conjecture states that if $p$ is an odd prime and $k$ is a natural number larger than $1$; then $a((p^{k+1}-1)/2)=p\cdot a((p^k-1)/2)$.

Computer testing of the generalized conjecture shows that there is no counterexample for $k$ and $p$ both up to $1000$. My question is to find a proof or a disproof to the generalized conjecture, and if that was not possible then at least finding a proof or a disproof to the non-generalized conjecture.
Thank you.

Comment: Your conjecture is equivalent to non-existence of order-$(k+1)$ Wieferich primes (satisfying $p^{k+1} \mid 2^{p-1}-1$). As we do not even know if order-2 Wieferich primes exist besides the known two, there is little hope to prove your or Ordowski's conjectures. On the other hand, if $p$ is not a Wieferich prime, then both statements are more or less trivial.

Comment: @Max Alekseyev I must say that Michel Marcus found some counterexamples if we assume p is not prime. you can see the history.

Comment: If $p$ is not prime, then anything can happen :)